# Excel 2007- Conditional Formatting- Formatting a cell based on values in a range of cells

Tags: excel, xls, conditional-operator

I have to use the following formula to format a cell based on a range of cells.

> =IF($D$35=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$36=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$37=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$38=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$39=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$40=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$41=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$42=$AD$34+$A$3,1,IF($D$43=$AD$34+$A$3,1,0)))))))))

The range of cells is D35 to D43. The condition to be met is a specific date (designated by AD34+A3). The formula above works perfectly. However, I know there is a better way. I have tried using INDIRECT, and OFFSET commands to specify the range of cells. I have not been able to get the syntax right.

I have worked on this for days, can someone please show me what i am missing? I would prefer a solution that does not require VBL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

=IFERROR(MATCH(AD34+A3,D35:D43,0),0)

Comment: The Match function searches for a value in a range of cells. So it starts with AD34+A3 and tries to find that in the D35 to D43 range. If it does not find a match, it returns NA# unless you then wrap it in the iferror function.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. You have saved me a ton of time and file space.